# how call a single product and display it on a webpage

Tags: laravel

Was trying to call up from the database using this code:

```
  $product = Product::where('id','=','product_id')->get();
  return View::make(products.singles)->with('product', $product);
```

But I get this error;

> Object of class llluminate\view\view could not be converted to int

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return View::make(products.singles)->with('product', $product);
```

to

```
return View::make('products.singles')->with('product', $product);
```

And I'm also guessing this is wrong:

```
$product = Product::where('id','=','product_id')->get();
```

should probably be something like this (but I cant be sure without more of your code):

```
$product = Product::where('id','=', $product_id)->get();
```

Comment: After I tried your code correction u directed i had an error undefined variable:product_id

Comment: well - you need to define the variable for the product id you are searching for...

Comment: How do i define my $product_ id to call an individual product from the database

Comment: ...sorry - but if you cannot even define a variable in PHP then I think you need to do some PHP lessons before moving any further. I recommend www.laracasts.com

Comment: How do I define my variable